# Display data in drop down based on another dropdown list

Tags: c#

I have two drop down list in which i am getting data displayed from database.
When College Name in DropDownList2 is selected only related branches must be shown in of that college in DropDownList1 for this i had used a Stored Procedure and it was working fine when i run it in manually by passing Parameteres.

But while executing code i all branches are displayed.do i need have any Post Back ?
Please help me in this scenario.

Below is my code:

```
string queryString = "select College_Name from Colleges";
            string constring = System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["ConnDBForum"].ConnectionString;
            SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection(constring);
            SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand(queryString, connection);
            connection.Open();
            DataTable dt = new DataTable();
            SqlDataAdapter ad = new SqlDataAdapter(command);
            ad.Fill(dt);

            if (dt.Rows.Count > 0)
            {
                DropDownList2.Items.Insert(0, new ListItem(String.Empty, String.Empty));
                DropDownList2.DataSource = dt;
                DropDownList2.DataTextField = "College_Name";
                DropDownList2.DataValueField = "College_Name";
                DropDownList2.DataBind();
                DropDownList2.Items.Insert(0, new ListItem(String.Empty, String.Empty));
            }


            SqlCommand Cmd = new SqlCommand("Branch_display", connection);
            Cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
            Cmd.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@College_Name", DropDownList2.SelectedValue));
            DataTable dt1 = new DataTable();
            SqlDataAdapter ad1 = new SqlDataAdapter(Cmd);
            ad1.Fill(dt1);

            if (dt1.Rows.Count > 0)
            {

                DropDownList1.DataSource = dt1;
                DropDownList1.DataTextField = "Name";
                DropDownList1.DataValueField = "Name";
                DropDownList1.DataBind();
                DropDownList1.Items.Insert(0, new ListItem(String.Empty, String.Empty));
            }
            connection.Close();
        }
```

Comment: set `autopostback` property of `DropDownList2` to `true`. In `DropDownList2.selectedindexchanged` event ... you populate the required data to `DropDownList1`.

Answer (score 0):

yes you need to have a post back somethink like this should help

```
      protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

                if(!IsPostBack)
                {
          string queryString = "select College_Name from Colleges";
    string   constring=System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["ConnDBForum"].ConnectionString;

                SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection(constring);
                SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand(queryString, connection);
                connection.Open();
                DataTable dt = new DataTable();
                SqlDataAdapter ad = new SqlDataAdapter(command);
                ad.Fill(dt);

                if (dt.Rows.Count > 0)
                {
                    DropDownList2.Items.Insert(0, new ListItem(String.Empty, String.Empty));
                    DropDownList2.DataSource = dt;
                    DropDownList2.DataTextField = "College_Name";
                    DropDownList2.DataValueField = "College_Name";
                    DropDownList2.DataBind();
                    DropDownList2.Items.Insert(0, new ListItem(String.Empty, String.Empty));

                }
 connection.Close();
            }
        }
```

asp.net render

```
  <asp:dropdownlist ID=" DropDownList2" runat="server" AutoPostBack="True" OnSelectedIndexChanged=" DropDownList2_SelectedIndexChanged">
```

and action

```
private void  DropDownList2_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{ 

string   constring=System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["ConnDBForum"].ConnectionString;


     SqlCommand Cmd = new SqlCommand("Branch_display", connection);
            Cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
            Cmd.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@College_Name", DropDownList2.SelectedValue));
            DataTable dt1 = new DataTable();
            SqlDataAdapter ad1 = new SqlDataAdapter(Cmd);
            ad1.Fill(dt1);

            if (dt1.Rows.Count > 0)
            {

                DropDownList1.DataSource = dt1;
                DropDownList1.DataTextField = "Name";
                DropDownList1.DataValueField = "Name";
                DropDownList1.DataBind();
                DropDownList1.Items.Insert(0, new ListItem(String.Empty, String.Empty));
            }
            connection.Close();
}
```